# Is a graph uniquely determined by its weighted 2-step graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected graph.  Define the *2-step* graph $G^{(2)}$ of $G$ to be the weighted graph whose vertices are the same as those of $G$ but whose edges correspond to 2-step paths in $G$.  Thus the weight of an edge $(u,v)$ is the number of distinct vertices $w$ such that $(u,w)$ and $(w,v)$ are both edges in $G$.  (In particular, the weight of $(u,u)$ is the degree of $u$ for every vertex $u$.)  My question:

> Are there two non-isomorphic graphs $G$ and $H$ such that $G^{(2)}$ is isomorphic to $H^{(2)}$?

My intuition says that the answer should be "yes", but I'm unable to construct an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer assumes a path cannot contain repeated edges or vertices. The OP is interested in the case where edges and vertices can be repeated. See comments below.

Here is an example of two non-isomorphic graphs $G$ and $H$ with isomorphic 2-step graphs $G^{(2)}$ and $H^{(2)}$.

[image: example]

Comment: That's great, thanks!  Any chance you can adapt your example so that $G$ and $H$ are connected?

Comment: I don't see any way to modify this example to make both graphs connected. I thought for a few minutes and did could not come up with a connected example. I'll let you know if I am able to find one.

Comment: Your example resolves this question as I asked it (and I could not produce a disconnected example on my own) so I posted the connected case as a separate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878575/is-a-connected-graph-uniquely-determined-by-its-weighted-2-step-graph.

Comment: On further consideration I realized that your example doesn't quite work: the isolated vertex in $G^{(2)}$ has a self edge with weight $3$ while the isolated vertex in $H^{(2)}$ has no self edge.  But the example has nevertheless been food for thought...

Comment: What is your definition of path? It sounds like you are allowing edges to be repeated?

So, in that case every vertex will have a self edge (loop) in the 2-step graph with weight equal to the degree of the vertex?

Comment: Yes, that is correct: the weight of every self edge is the degree of the vertex in the original graph.  My motivation for this definition comes from random walks; to compute distributions associated with two step random walks you want to allow the walk to cross the same edge twice in a row.

Comment: I have edited many answer to include the definition of path I was using. You many want to edit your question (this question and the related question you posted) to include the definition of path you want to be used. Like many terms in graph theory there can be some ambiguity as different author use slightly different definitions.

Comment: What you refer to as a "path" I would call a "walk", this Wikipedia article discusses this as well as the ambiguity I described in my previous comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Walks. Nothing wrong with how you have, but you just need to be careful in graph theory (and other areas of math). Definitions aren't always universal.